# Add jQuery variables in src of an image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, tags

I have a website and based on language `en, sq or el,` I want to change image source. So I have a folder named screenshots then there are three folders: `en, sq and el`.

For example the URL for a picture named 'slide-phone.png' is:

```
static/img/screenshots/en/slide-phone.png
static/img/screenshots/sq/slide-phone.png
static/img/screenshots/el/slide-phone.png
```

I want to take attribute lang of HTML tag and then to add it to the source of the image, but for some reasons, it's not working.

My code looks like this:

```
<html lang="{{ _('en') }}">
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(e){
       var language = $('html').attr('lang');
});
</script>
...
 <img  id="slide-phone-1-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/screenshots/' + language+'slide-phone.png') }}" >
```

I'm using python and jinja. Any help :)

EDIT:

I also tried like this but the problem is that I want to use jinja and for that I need to change this code:

```
<html lang="{{ _('en') }}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(e){
           var language = $('html').attr('lang')
           img_url = 'img/screenshots/'+ language+'/slide-phone.png';
           $('#slide-phone-img').attr('src',img_url);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: how should it work ? How and where you call your variable language ?

Comment: @MKAD inside the src in image div ?

Comment: you cant call your language variable out of <script type="text/javascript"> tags

Comment: is any way to do it ?

Comment: let me know 
If it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
       var language = $('html').attr('lang');
       var new_url = $('#slide-phone-1-img').attr("src").replace("language", language);
       console.log(new_url);
       $('#slide-phone-1-img').remove();
       $('#imges').prepend('<img id="slide-phone-1-img" src="'+new_url+'" />');

$('#show').html( $('#slide-phone-1-img').attr("src").replace("language", language));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="{{ _('en') }}">
   <body>
    <div id="imges">
     <img  id="slide-phone-1-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/screenshots/language slide-phone.png') }}" > 
    </div>   
    <div id="show">
      <p></p>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did a console.log and it shows the good link like this :/static/img/screenshots/en/slide-phone.png , but in the scr is not replaced. Is this maybe because page loads and after it the jquery code is executed?

Comment: youe mean the src in your html img tag is not replaced?

Comment: if I understood you correctly, you want to change your code in your example.html after jQuery once? from  <img  id="slide-phone-1-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/screenshots/language slide-phone.png') }}" > .....  to  <img  id="slide-phone-1-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/screenshots/{{ _('en') }} slide-phone.png') }}" >  right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105132/discussion-between-mkad-and-tinmat).

Comment: Yes exactly,ur code works as I said before If I do a console.log($('#slide-phone-1-img').attr("src").replace("language", language)) it gives the right url, but the url in src is not changed .

Comment: the reason is JavaScript doesn't have access to writing files. img tag is not change in your data.html but in your browser source.

Comment: see my post I have customize my code, maybe it helps..... after i generate new path with your desirable language variable i remove old img tag and append the new one with the current src.

Comment: Now the error is saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: show me your <header> </header> please or your whole html